# Create catalog price rule for custom options

Tags: custom-options, catalog-price-rules

Is it possible to create/apply catalog price rule for product custom options? So that i can have a discount for particular custom option choosed by customer.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Does it have to be the a 'custom option'?

Comment: I wonder this too. Why would they not apply the discount to custom options? Is there some logical reason? Catalog price rules seem totally unusable with products with custom options with extra price.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible, the price rules can only be applied to attributes.
Maybe it would be an option to create a configurable product?

Comment: will it possible to add rule by custom option "SKU"?

Comment: that's an attribute. Or you mean the custom options SKU? in the second case it's not possible)

Comment: yes you are right... its custom options SKU? Anyway thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 1):

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-shopping-cart-promotion-rule-for-product-with-custom-options/

I found this great and easy 5 minute Tutorial. Copying & Pasting 3 Files allows you to use the **product's SKU** combined with the **Custom Options SKU** in a Price Rule:

e.g. for a T-Shirt (SKU: T_Shirt) available in Large/Medium/Small and Red/Blue/Green you can use `T_Shirt-Large-Red` or `T_Shirt-Medium-Blue` as `Cart Item Attribute` in Price Rules.

Hope it still helps someone, looks like this is the easiest way and worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This will only work for shopping cart price rules, the question was about catalog price rules

Comment: You are right, but there is an option to apply the shopping cart rule only to cart items "matching the following conditions".
This way you're able to create a discount for certain products based on a specific custom option.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `product attribute` for your desired `attribute set` and use that attribute in the conditions for your price rule.

Just make sure when creating a new attribute that you set the `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` option to `yes`, this way this attribute will show up as an option in the dropdown menu for the conditions. (next to `SKU`, `Category` and `Attribute set`)